# How to connect to a MongoDB database from an application deployed on ZEIT Now?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, vercel

I have deployed an application on Zeit Now using ExpressJS. The application makes a connection to MongoDB using Mongoose. However, the state of the connection, which I obtain using `mongoose.connection.readyState` is displayed as 2, which denotes 'connecting'.

I tried running the application locally and it works fine, where I am able to write to the database.

```
const connectionURL = "mongodb+srv://MONGODB_USERNAME:MONGOD_BPASSWORD@cluster1-23abc.mongodb.net/DATABASE_NAME?retryWrites=true"

expressApp.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Listening to port 3000");
});

mongoose
  .connect(
    connectionURL, { useNewUrlParser: true }
  )
  .then(function() {
    console.log("db connected!");
  });

expressApp.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.write(`Connection State:  ${mongoose.connection.readyState}\n`);
  res.end();
});
```

I would expect `mongoose.connection.readyState` to be 1, which denotes 'connected'.
However, `mongoose.connection.readyState` is stuck at 2, which denotes 'connecting'.

Also, `now logs` does not show any errors.

Comment: I had the same issue with MongoDB databases and now. It works perfectly fine locally but when I upload it, that's it not working.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to cache your MongoDB connection so you won't have to make a new connection on each lamda call.

You can make an lib folder and empty mongoose.js file (lib/mongoose.js) as I did and place this code inside:

```
`import mongoose from 'mongoose';

let cachedDb = null;

console.log('outside-cachedDB:', cachedDb);
async function connectToDatabase(uri) {
  if (cachedDb) {
    console.log('=> using cached database instance');
    return cachedDb;
  }

  // If no connection is cached, create a new one
  const db = await mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });

  console.log('New MongoDB Connected');

  // Cache the database connection and return the connection
  cachedDb = db;
  return db;
}

export default async () => {
  await connectToDatabase(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
};`
```

Then call this custom mongoose function in any lamda that needs a mongoDB connection:

```
`import express from "express";
import mongoose from "../lib/mongoose";

const app = express();

// @route Get api/connect
// @desc Tests post route
// @access Public
app.get("*", async (req, res) => {
   await mongoose();
  // Code to query your DB or whatever here
});

export default app;`
```

You don't have to use express of course, but I personally haven't moved on to newer solutions. One of these days I'll learn micro.js.